# How to deploy WPF .net Core application to raspberry pi 4

Tags: wpf, .net-core, raspberry-pi

Is there a way to deploy WPF .net Core application to raspberry pi 4? (using Wndows 10 IoT Core or any other way). Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Maybe the Avalonia framework is a way you could go. It's cross plattform an very similar to WPF.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will research it and if I get through I will try to post some guide for other here. Can you provide any links with sample implementation for raspberry pi 4? I didn't manage to find anything meaningful. Best regards.

Comment: https://edi.wang/post/2019/9/29/setup-net-core-30-runtime-and-sdk-on-raspberry-pi-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you manage to install Windows 10 IoT Core on your device, it won't let you run traditional full-blown Windows desktop applications such as WPF and WinForms apps so I am afraid this isn't supported, at least not officially.

You may run a [UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) on Windows 10 IoT Core though.

Comment: You'll also need to figure out how to install Windows 10 IoT Core on a Raspberry Pi4. There's no offical support for that yet.

Comment: It seems this guy has made it:

https://discourse.pi64.win/t/how-to-installing-windows-10-arm64-17134-on-your-raspberry-pi-3-and-4/488

Comment: There are apparently still some limitations like max. usage of 1GB of RAM what would in my case be very limiting.

Comment: Yes. Trying to running a WPF app on a Raspberry Pi is most probably a bad idea.

Comment: What do you suggest instead. What ist the best approach to develop for Raspberry PI  (using C# ) ? This 1G limitation applies also for UWP.